# glfw closes as soon as it opens on visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw

This test code causes the opengl window to open and disappear as soon as it appears. Yes I am compiling the library from source.

What's wrong with my code?

```
#include<glad\glad.h>
#include<GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
if (glfwInit() == false)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLFW Failed to initialise");
    return -1;
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test OPENGL", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "window failed to open");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
//system("pause");
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLAD");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't have a event loop.

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be. You create a window, but shortly after your program terminates, so your window dies again. You need some kind of loop to keep your program alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need an event loop to pump the message queue and swap buffers](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick_guide.html):

```
while( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    // draw stuff

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```